# Using a custom font throughout the project

Tags: c#, .net, prism

I've got a Prism project with a dozen modules in it.
I want to use a custom font (a .TTF file, to be specific) in all the modules.
When I put the .ttf file in the module folder - it works, but what if I add a dozen more modules?
So, I want to have the file in one place. 
At tried to put the font in %projectname%.Web/Clientbin, because it worked with images and everything, but it doesn't work. =(
Can you give me some advise?

Example of the code:

```
<HyperlinkButton
FontFamily="/fonts/AZGR45_C.TTF#AZGaramondC">
www.samplelink.com
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PRISM generally means you have a few projects.

- Application.Shell: Your startup application containing the app.xaml
- Application.Module: Your different modules
- Application.Infrastructure. Containing general classes for your
  application. Every module and the shell has a reference to this
  project. In example you might have Interfaces for certain services
  like CustomerServices. This also allows you to have certain styling
  or datatemplate or even fonts in this Infrastructure project

Hope this helps